# Emulate Navigation Drawer Icon on Android ActionBar without Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I used the [SlidingLayer](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib)  library in my Android proyect and I want to emulate the home button as if I used a Navigation Drawer. I am using ActionBar too, How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Find this blog post](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/06/navigation-drawer-icon-in-action-bar.html)
It looks similar to your question

`public void updateNavigationDrawerIcon(Drawable drawable) {
Method setHomeAsUpIndicator;
           try {
           setHomeAsUpIndicator = ActionBar.class.getDeclaredMethod("setHomeAsUpIndicator",            Drawable.class);
           setHomeAsUpIndicator.invoke(getActionBar(), drawable);
           } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                      Log.e("CHECK", "No Such Method");
                      View home = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
                      ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) home.getParent();
                      int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
                      if (childCount == 2) {
                                final View first = parent.getChildAt(0);
                                final View second = parent.getChildAt(1);
                               final View up = first.getId() == android.R.id.home ? second : first;
                                 ((ImageView) up).setImageDrawable(drawable);
                      }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
}`

ALL THE BEST